# screenshare in chrome with wayland + pipewire in KDE

Tags: arch-linux, kde, wayland, plasma, pipewire

I am using archlinux with pipewire, wireplumber, plasma and xdg-desktop-portal-kde

```
plasmashell --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ✔  23:48:31  
plasmashell 5.26.3

    ~  pipewire --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ✔  23:49:02  
pipewire
Compiled with libpipewire 0.3.60
Linked with libpipewire 0.3.60

    ~  wireplumber --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ✔  23:49:10  
wireplumber
Compiled with libwireplumber 0.4.12
Linked with libwireplumber 0.4.12
```

If I try to record any of my windows with OBS, the desktop-portal window for selecting the window opens and I can select any windows and it works fine, I can see the window content in OBS.

However, in chrome and in firefox, I get the desktop-portal window, I select a window and it just shares a black screen.

I have no clue how to fix this and its really annoying. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox run with XWayland by default, and Piprewire can only capture "true Wayland" windows.

You can opt in to using Wayland in both browsers though:

- for Chrome: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chromium#Native_Wayland_support (though you can actually also use `chrome://flags` if you prefer: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/09/enable-wayland-firefox-chrome/)
- for Firefox: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/firefox#Wayland

Comment: I think you are confused. First, pipewire can capture XWayland windows perfectly, as each XWayland window it a Wayland client itself. Second, my issue is not that I can't capture Chrome, I can't capture neither wayland nor xwayland windows. Third, I capture perfectly from OBS any window (Wayland and XWayland). I can also capture perfectly from gnome. Finally, I can capture fine using AMD/Intel GPUs.